# Why only the spring-related logs conform to the format I defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j, spring-cloud-feign

Why in the logs printed in the console, only the spring-related logs conform to the format I defined, and other logs (such as alibaba nacos, hikari datasource or the logs output by myself in the code) do not conform to the format I defined:
[image: console log snapshot]

I have tried to exclusion logback dependency in my project.

My log format is as follows:

```
<Property name="TRACE">
            [${APP_NAME}, %X{traceId}, %X{spanId}, %X{spanExportable}, %X{EagleEye-TraceID}]
        </Property>
        <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_MESSAGE">
            %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n${sys:EXCEPTION}
        </property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">
            %clr{%d{${DATA}}}{faint} %clr{${LEVEL}} %clr{${TRACE}} ${sys:CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_MESSAGE}
</Property>
```